# Printf with short integer compiler warning

Tags: c, printf, short

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  short i = 1;

  printf("%hd\n", i);
  printf("%hd\n", i * i);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this gives the warning `warning: format specifies type 'short' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat] printf("%hd\n", i * i);`.

Removing the `printf("%hd\n", i * i);` statement produces no warning.

Have I done something wrong? It is my understanding that since `i` has type `short int` that the value of the expression `i * i` has type `short int` but then `printf` performs an integer promotion to convert this `short int` result to  `int` form before converting this `int` to `short` again (due to the conversion specifier).

I don't particularly see what is wrong about the code though. Is it just a warning telling me to be careful of the possibility that a more complicated expression than a simple `short int` variable being passed as an argument to `printf` corresponding to the `%hd` conversion specifier might result in overflow? Thanks!

Comment: in `i * i` the arguments to the multiplication undergo ["integer promotions"](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1) and ["usual arithmetic conversions"](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) and become `int` even before the multiplication is done. The final result of the multiplication is an `int`.

Comment: @pmg Please make this an answer.

Comment: Ah right with the multiplicative operators the usual arithmetic conversions are applied on the operands and the usual arithmetic conversions itself specifies that the operands ```i``` in ```i * i``` undergo integer promotions making the value of ```i``` an ```int``` before the multiplication is performed. So essentially I am passing an ```int``` argument when it is expecting a ```short```.  Performing the multiplication prior to the call of ```printf``` and assigning it to a ```short``` will remove the warning. But this particular warning isn't one I need worry about right?

Comment: The above program was just a snippet of a slightly larger but still very small program with the purpose of seeing at what number overflow occurs.

Comment: See [constants defined in `<limits.h>`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1) ... `SHRT_MAX` et al :-)

Comment: Kind of a duplicate: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `i * i` the arguments to the multiplication undergo ["integer promotions"](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1) and ["usual arithmetic conversions"](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) and become `int` before the multiplication is done. The final result of the multiplication is an int.

The type of `i * i` is `int` (when type of `i` is `int`, `short`, `char`, or `_Bool`).

---

When you call printf with `"%hd"` the corresponding argument should be a `short`. What happens is that it is automatically converted to `int` and it's an `int` that printf sees. The internal code of printf will convert that `int` to a `short` to do its thing.
Problem is if you start with an `int` value outside the range of `short`.

```
short i = SHRT_MAX;
int j = i * i;
short k = i * i; // overflow while assigning
printf("%hd %hd", j, k);
//                ^ (kinda) overflow inside the innards of printf
```